# Erlang - Anonymouos Function

Tags: erlang, anonymous-function

If i call the test(), it doesnt work. Can someone explain this ?.

```
-module(anony).

-export([test/0, test1/0]).

test1() -> "hello".

test() ->
   C = fun(F) -> Val = F(), io:format("~p ", [Val]) end, 
   lists:foreach(debug, [test1]).
```

Comment: You should specify what was intended result. Though I guess you want it to print "hello", right?

Answer (score 7):

`test1` on its own is simply an atom, not a reference to the local function.    To create a reference to the function use fun Function/Arity as below.

```
-module(anony).

-export([test/0, test1/0]).

test1() -> "hello".

test() ->
    C = fun(F) -> Val = F(), io:format("~p ", [Val]) end,
    lists:foreach(C, [fun test1/0]).
```

You could also construct an anonymous function that calls `test1` like this:  `fun() -> test1() end`, but there's no reason to that unless you have additional values you want to pass in or the like.

Answer (score 3):

The other two answers do actually answer the question.  I just want to add to them.

I expect that you want to be able to pass an atom and call the function with that name.  This is not possible for local functions.  It is very possible for exported functions though.

So you can do something like (my only change is to add "?MODULE:", and to change "debug" to "C"):

```
-module(anony).

-export([test/0, test1/0]).

test1() -> "hello".

test() ->
    C = fun(F) -> Val = ?MODULE:F(), io:format("~p ", [Val]) end, 
    lists:foreach(C, [test1]).
```

Comment: An interesting alternative. I wonder how it compares to the other answer (using fun test1/0 to make an explicit function reference) in terms of performance.

Comment: My solution will be a little bit slower because of the "external" function call. On the other hand they solve two different problems.

Answer (score 2):

First, `C` variable hasn't been used at all, and second you should wrap the `test1` with a `fun/end`:

```
-module(anony).

-export([test/0, test1/0]).

test1() -> "hello".

test() ->
     C = fun(F) -> Val = F(), io:format("~p ", [Val]) end,
     lists:foreach(C, [fun() -> test1() end]).
```

Comment: Your `fun() -> test1 end` doesn't call `test1` at all, it just returns the atom `test1`.